# Create an ASP.net Web App that takes pdf files as input (upload) in Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I need to add a button to my ASP.net web app that takes a pdf file and does some stuff to it.

I already have the "stuff" code working, I just need the working button that supplies it with a pdf file.

I have found various resources specifying how to do this, but they are all in C# and Windows Forms, which is not what I am using, I'm using an ASP.net web App with Visual Basic.

So far I have this HTML

```
<INPUT id="oFile" type="file" runat="server" NAME="oFile">Select the image file to upload to the server:
<asp:button id="btnUpload" type="submit" text="Upload" runat="server"></asp:button>
<asp:Panel ID="frmConfirmation" Visible="False" Runat="server">
    <asp:Label id="lblUploadResult" Runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

I know I need a Click event handler for the Upload button, but I can't figure out how to write it.

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-Upload-File-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx  -- I would recommend using the ````FileUpload Control```` and there are quite a few examples of how the code-behind would look.  Typically a button click event will then read the file in the control and you can determine how to handle it.

Comment: That works! Thank you